# Symfony build-in server curl return http code 0

Tags: php, curl, symfony-3.4

recently I'm dealing with the symfony3.4. I was using the web server nginx 1.2 in linux VMware and the curl works fine, but when I start to use symfony build-in server the curl in my controller is not working. I couldn't find the problem and also not able to find the solution within searching many websites..

it wrok like this:

the controller use curl to call another controller to get the json data. i'm pretty sure the api side is work fine, because everytime when i call the api with no matter curl in commend line or postman(chrome plug) all return complete json data and http code 200. I have checked the info, always return 0, but if the url I set other webpage is 200 too. works fine.

```
    $ch = curl_init();
    $options = array(
        CURLOPT_URL => 'http://127.0.0.0.1:8000/api/create',
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
        CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 1,
        CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
        CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "GET",
        CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT => 10,
        CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false,
        CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST => false,
    );
    curl_setopt_array($ch, $options);
    $result = json_decode(curl_exec($ch), false);
```

dump(curl_getinfo($ch)); // http code = 0

The timeout set 1 sec because doesn't matter I set how long, the result will always reach the time I set. I'm guessing because of symfony's server setting